# Building my App for Android N Development Preview

Tags: android

I am looking at building in the changes to support some of the new features for Android N.

At the moment the app targets API 23 and min SDK is 14. I understand that for the developer preview, the min SDK and the target SDK have to match, so in this they would both need to be set to N.

I obviously want the app to support more than just Android N but I don't want to publish a separate app, just for N users.

How do other developers do this? I believe I've seen other do this in the past. If I upload a new APK to the developer console, this will replace the current version so that only N users can install the app, which I don't want. Is there a way to publish an additional APK so that users on public release version of Android get one APK and users on the N preview get the new N build of the APK.

Comment: I don't think that the Play Store supports developer preview versions of Android. After all, they have this in [the license terms](https://developer.android.com/preview/license.html): "You agree not to publicly distribute or ship any application using this Preview as this Preview will no longer be supported after the official Android SDK is released."

Comment: I did just notice that on the developer console that it can't be published yet. I thought other developers had done with previous preview versions, maybe when they're a little further down the line, or maybe I'm completely wrong.

Comment: yeah you cannot publish app built with developer previews